# Making glass like button in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, android-selector

I am making glass like button by specifying style in gradient.xml file but i am not getting any output and i am using this style to all the buttons of my applications...i am a newbie please help.. Here is my code

gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_focused="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <gradient 
        android:startColor="#2F000000" 
        android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE"  
        android:angle="270" />
    <!-- <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#bb00ff00" /> -->
    <corners 
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp" />
   </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
   <shape>
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#2F000000" 
        android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" 
        android:angle="270" />
   <!--  <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#bb00ff00" /> -->
    <corners 
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>
 <item>
<shape>
     <gradient
        android:startColor="#2F000000" 
        android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" 
        android:angle="180" />
        <!-- <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/cream_dark"
        android:endColor="@color/cream"
        android:angle="270"/> -->

     <!--  <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        android:color="#ffffffff" />  -->
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: post your layout code for button.

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPrescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:onClick="buttonPrescriptionClicked"
        android:text="@string/button_text_prescription"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

Comment: Post the whole layout as you are not providing the information about the parent layout of the button. If there is `android:orientation="horizontal"` then set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the `Button` and`android:layout_height="0dp"` for `android:orientation="vertical"` in parent layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting something like this

[image]

Then find the code below...

glass.xml in drawable folder.

```
<item android:state_focused="false"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" android:startColor="#2F000000" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" android:startColor="#2F000000" />

        <corners android:radius="3dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="180" android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" android:startColor="#2F000000" />

        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

layout file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/glass"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Trail"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Hope that it helps you....

Answer (score 1):

Make a Separate .xml ( For eg. xyz.xml)  file in drawable and paste your gradient code in it.
And then give the background to your button as android:background ="@drawable/xyz"

Example :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mirror Button"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/xyz"
        android:gravity="center" />
```